# How to utilize a UISegmentedControl With a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UITableViewController` that has 5 different sections, & each section contains an individual cell. In section 1 I have a `UISegmentedControl`that offers two options by default segment 1 is picked so the rest of the sections (the other 4) correspond with segment 1. However, the problem that I am having is: Having the ability to switch to another `UITableView` that has other sections & cells that would correspond to segment 2, when of course segment 2 is selected in the `UISegmentedControl`

I am using storyboards for this project.

I know that the question of how to achieve this has been asked a thousand times, and I know how to do this if I was working with regular view controllers, I am new to working with `UITableViewController` and this is really giving me a hard time.

Things that I have tried:

**No.1:**  I tried deleting the `UITableViewController` all together and replacing with a normal `ViewController` and sub a `UITableView` to the main view. The problem with that is that I was given an error by xcode because static cells require a `UITableViewController` to work, (unfortunately I am working with static cells).

**No.2:** I have tried to hide the cells with a conditional from the `UISegmentedControl` to only display the appropriate cells with the appropriate selection, but this did not work because I was not able to add my other sections & cells on top (as I would have normally done with regular `UIViewController`.

This is the code that I used to try method # 2 :

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0)
    {
        upick= 0;
        self.lengthCell.hidden=NO;
        self.widthCell.hidden=NO;
        self.depthCell.hidden=NO;
        self.flowCell.hidden=YES;

    }
    else if (selectedSegment == 1)
    {
        upick =1;
        self.lengthCell.hidden=YES;
        self.widthCell.hidden=YES;
        self.depthCell.hidden=YES;
        self.flowCell.hidden=NO;
    }

}
```

**No.3:** Countless hours of research on the net but can't seem to find the exact results I am looking for, most show how to do this with a `UIViewController` and the steps are different for this particular case.

I would really appreciate some advice & overall direction to take from here because I am stuck. Thanks guys!

Comment: Why not just have custom cells for each case, and `reloadData` when each section of the segmented control is selected?

Comment: How did you setup the UISegmentedControl? Directly in the storyboard or programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Have all the cells you need available in your table view controller.
2. In your table view's datasource methods (i.e. `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) you can set all the correct numbers and data for the two states.
3. When the segmented control changes, you can do two things. Either you simply `reloadData`, as was suggested before, but then you do not get any animations. Or you use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to get the animation effect.

E.g. showing sections 1-2 in case 1 and sections 3-6 in case 2 (section 0 being the top section); each section has 2 rows

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return _control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 3 : 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return section == 0 ? 1 : 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
   // .. the usual boilerplate
   if (_control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { /* configure cell */ }
   else { /*do the same for the other case */ }
   return cell;
}

-(void)segmentedControlDidChange:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    NSIndexSet *indexes;
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1,4)];
        [_tableView deleteSections:indexes 
                  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1,2)];
        [_tableView insertSections:indexes 
                  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [_tableView reloadSections:indexes 
                  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    else {
         // do the reverse
    }
    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I like the outcome I would receive with your answer, would you mind posting some sample code? I apologize I am just a little confused since I am not too familiar utilizing the `UITableView`, Thanks! @Mundi

Comment: can this be achieved when using storyboards to make the static cells?@Mundi

Comment: Not sure. Static cells is a strange and restricted beast. If you want to do anything fancy, it has to be dynamic. (Hiding and showing is by definition "dynamic".)

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you need to switch between 2 table views using     UISegmentedControl. You can use UIViewController and add 2 UITableViews to it and keep your UISegmentedControl outside the table views. Then may be you can manage it in the following method:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0)
    {
    //show Table1 and hide Table2
    // Reload Table1

    }
    else if (selectedSegment == 1)
    {
    //show Table2 and hide Table1
    // Reload Table2
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with that is that when I try adding another `UITableView` to my `TableViewController` it does not sub it off of the `TableViewController` unlike if I was doing this with normal ViewController for example, so upon build I get the following error because of that added `UITableView` `Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances` @Nameet

Comment: sure, thats one of the reasons why using a tableview controller might not be a good idea